# data table columns data not display in mobile

Tags: datatables

I am using datatables and it working fine in desktop but in mobile there is no data load to table. What is the problem?

Here is my code:

```
$('#users-table').DataTable({
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [
      'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
  ],
  scrollY: 300,
  destroy: true,
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  responsive:true,
  ajax: '/depart/get_datatable/',
  columns: [
    { data: 'depart_name', name: 'departs.depart_name' },
    { data: 'levels', name: 'departs.levels' },
    { data: 'name', name: 'colleges.name' },
    { data: 'action', name: 'action',searchable:false, sortable: false,
            className: 'text-right' }  
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the  solution is add cache :false to ajax call 
ajax:{
         url:......,
         cache:false
}